# Java get text between the last square brackets in a String with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to extract the text between the last brackets of a string. This is how it looks like:

```
String text= "[text1][text2][text3][text4]";
```

I need to get

```
String result = "text4"
```

I have tried with Regex but i can't manage to make it work. I would appreciate some help with getting the regex and the substring. Thank you very much

Comment: `I have tried with Regex but i can't manage to make it work` ... please include your attemtped Java code (whose absence is likely the sole reason for all the downvotes and close votes)

Comment: Instead of a regex, I would use the `lastIndexOf` method to find the last `[` and `]`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - [Lack of research effort is not, and has never been, a reason to close a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357505/10819573)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash 1) I didn't vote to close the question, but others did, 2) the OP's showing us what it has already tried would set the stage for someone to answer.  That didn't happen, despite my request.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex, `.+(\[.+\])$` and capture group(1).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "[text1][text2][text3][text4]";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".+(\\[.+\\])$").matcher(text);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[text4]
```

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eDt8xK/1):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex. You can use `lastIndexOf`

```
String text= "[text1][text2][text3][text4]";
System.out.println(text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("[")+1, text.lastIndexOf("]")));
```